# web3 methods not implemented

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, javascript

I'm running a geth node on the testnet and trying to run web3.js method from my node server code.

Here's my code

```
var Web3 = require("web3");
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://0.0.0.0:8545'));
console.log(web3.net.peerCount);
```

However, I'm getting net_peerCount method not implemented error.

Infact, I'm getting a similar method not implemented error when I try to access any net or eth methods.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

I got it working by running the command i found in the docs https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#adminstartrpc

```
admin.startRPC("127.0.0.1", 8545, "*", "web3,db,net,eth")
```

from my geth console!

Thanks for the suggestions :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit about that command, maybe include a quote from the docs? Then you should mark it as answered.

Answer (score 4):

Try not to mix cases when you use the web3 variable.  When you specify the address, I hope you didn't physically used 0.0.0.0.  For a local node, here's an exampe:

```
var web3=require('web3');
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
```

For reference, consult the Javascript-API help document in the doc dir.

Comment: I needed to add a rpcdomain when starting geth in oder to get access. To allow access from all domains you can use:
 geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain="*"

Answer (score 3):

This [answer on reddit](https://m.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4bm36z/ethereum_website_intergating/?ref=readnext_4) helped me.

Run geth with:

```
geth --rpc --rpcapi "web3,net,personal,eth"
```

The "personal" api is not exposed by default with the `--rpc` option. Once you do the above, it exposes all the ones listed, including personal which will allow you do do the `personal_unlockAccount` and `personal_newAccount` (which I'm assuming you are after).