# Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined from node web3.js app

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, json-rpc, nodejs

I'm getting `Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined` from my node.js application when it tries to execute a function.
My steps:

1. ethereum wallet 0.5.1 to deploy a contract to the testnet.
2. start the geth client version 1.3.3:

   ```
   $ geth --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcapi "eth,web3" --rpcport 8546 --networkid 5678 attach
   ```

(I can run `web3.eth.accounts` from within the geth console and it returns my locally created accounts)

3. used npm to install web3 version 0.15.3
4. from within the node shell:

   ```
   > var Web3 = require('web3')
   > web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8546"))
   > web3.version.api
   '0.15.3'
   > web3.eth.accounts
   Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined
   at Object.module.exports.InvalidResponse (/Users/jbowkett/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
   at HttpProvider.send (/Users/jbowkett/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:87:22)
   at RequestManager.send (/Users/jbowkett/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:58:32)
   at Eth.get [as accounts] (/Users/jbowkett/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/property.js:107:62)
   at repl:1:9
   at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:252:27)
   at bound (domain.js:287:14)
   at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
   at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:417:12)
   at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
   ```

Also :
`$ telnet localhost 8546`
yields no connection

Comment: `eth.accounts ` is undefined; try start geth with  `--etherbase` flag along with your address.

Comment: @NikhilM how come it works in the geth console?....I should have clarified, this seems to be the response I get for any methods I call on the web3 instance

Comment: So you have working accounts in geth? any CORS errors on the console?

Comment: @nikhilm Yes I believe so - I see no errors in geth for the same calls as I am trying to make over web3

Comment: This issue has been solved here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23719/invalid-json-rpc-response-undefined-when-running-web3-eth-accounts-node/25300#25300

Answer (score 10, accepted):

from the geth console:

`admin.startRPC("127.0.0.1", 8545, "*", "web3,db,net,eth")`

then I was able to reconnect in node, and list the accounts. (unsurprisingly, telnet responded on this port too after starting RPC from within geth)

Taken from here:

[web3 methods not implemented](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1225/web3-methods-not-implemented)