# Solidity Browser: Invalid JSON RPC response: "" where parity works on the background

Tags: solidity, parity

On my [solidity browser](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.10+commit.f0d539ae.js) I get following error: `Invalid JSON RPC response: ""`

The way I use solidity browser:
Download solidity-browser from the following [link](http://github.com/chriseth/browser-solidity): unzipped the files and loaded index.html into the browser. /user/Downloads/browser-solidity-gh-pages/index.html.

Based on the following [guide](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2083/4575) and [guide-2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9637/4575), I run parity as [follows](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13035/4575): Please note that parity works perfectly fine, I can deploy a contract from parity's browser (localhost:8080).

```
parity --chain parity.json --network-id 23422 --reserved-peers myPrivateNetwork.txt --jsonrpc-apis web3,eth,net,parity,parity_accounts,traces,rpc,parity_set --rpc --rpcport  8545 --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1
```

Even I added following parameters as suggested on the guides: `--rpc --rpcport  8545 --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1` it did not fix the `Invalid JSON RPC response: ""` problem.

When I run `parity` with this flag: `--rpcaddr localhost` instead of `--rpcaddr 127.0.0.1` it also gives following error: `Invalid JSONRPC listen host/port given: localhost:8545`

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: use solidity browser without https.

Comment: I was using solidity browser on my local, Download solidity-browser from the following link: https://github.com/chriseth/browser-solidity
unzipped the files and loaded index.html into the browser.
/user/Downloads/browser-solidity-gh-pages/index.html. @ 5chdn

Comment: how could I know, you linked the https version :)

Comment: Ups my bad, http version seems working but the contract never get deployed. Do you think is it possible to make it work with local solidity? @5chdn

Comment: Sure, why not?-

Comment: I tried on it also but it didn't work on my case giving the same error @5chdn