# web3.eth.accounts is Empty

Tags: web3js, testrpc, accounts

I'm following the tutorial here: https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2

First, I got the error `"Error: Invalid JSON RPC response"`. Then I search for answers and I found that I didn't run testrpc ( very "fullstack" tutorial, really, like the all other "complete" tutorials about ethereum...

Anyway, I found a solution [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1225/web3-methods-not-implemented), open another terminal and run geth console and type:

```
admin.startRPC("127.0.0.1", 8545, "*", "web3,db,net,eth")
```

This time I got an "empty" list for web3.eth.accounts. I tried to add manually but I couldn't do it also.

Is there any possible solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Answering my own question, I did not want to delete it, if someone encounters with the same problem, maybe get benefit from here.

To use web3js, solc and testrpc, **first of all update your node via nvm.** Than the problem will be solved. No need to run TestRPC inside of the geth. Just run it from node_modules/.bin/testrpc.

Answer (score 1):

In one console window run

> testrpc

if you don't have it run

> npm install ethereumjs-testrpc web3

Then in another console run

> node
>
> Web3 = require('web3')
>
> web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
>
> web3.eth.accounts

Comment: yes I knew it but without updating node version, it doesn't work. There's conflict because of the JS versioning (ES5-ES6). In the tesrpc code, as I understood, ES6 arrow functions used, so testrpc doesn't work on older versions of node.